# WhiteSource doesn't exclude directories

Tags: .net, security, nuget

The config file used to start the wss-unified-agent:

```
# Includes/Excludes Glob patterns - Please use only one exclude line and one include line #
###########################################################################################
includes=**/*.c,**/*.cc,**/*.cp,**/*.cpp,**/*.cxx,**/*.c\+\+,**/*.h,**/*.hh,**/*.hpp,**/*.hxx,**/*.h\+\+, **/*.c#,**/*.cs,**/*.csharp, **/*.js ,**/*.php,**/*.py,**/*.rb, **/*.java ,**/*.egg,**/*.whl ,**/*.gem, **/*.nupkg ,**/*.dll ,**/*.go,**/*.jar

#includes=**/*.m **/*.mm  **/*.js **/*.php
#includes=**/*.jar
#includes=**/*.gem **/*.rb
#includes=**/*.dll **/*.cs **/*.nupkg
#includes=**/*.tgz **/*.deb **/*.gzip **/*.rpm **/*.tar.bz2
#includes=**/*.zip **/*.tar.gz **/*.egg **/*.whl **/*.py

#Exclude file extensions or specific directories by adding **/*.<extension> or **/<excluded_dir>/**
excludes=**/packages/**
```

I tried excluding the **packages** folder using both **/packages/** and **packages/** syntax, but the directory still shows up under the analysis logs:

```
[DEBUG] [2021-01-15 13:42:17,495 +0200[ - total resolved projects =0
[INFO] [2021-01-15 13:42:17,495 +0200[ - Scanning directories [projectName\packages] for matching source/binary file types (may take a few minutes)
[DEBUG] [2021-01-15 13:42:17,496 +0200[ - Scanning projectName\packages
[DEBUG] [2021-01-15 13:42:17,496 +0200[ - Dependency file found location: projectName\packages\...
```

Comment: You actually used the right syntax, it's excludes= \**/packages/**. What is the directory you are running the scan from? Should be a top directory i.e projectName in your example, or higher.

Comment: I am using the -d parameter to pass the absolute file path to the agent : -d "top_directory_path".  I also tried to run the scan from the top folder, whitesource still scans the excluded folders.

Comment: Did you try it in double quotes `excludes="**/packages/**"`

Comment: My personal opinion on the Unified Agent is it's sh*t. But hey, guess we need to figure out how it works ourselves.